Reference book for the Gromov-Hausdorff Distance
I have recently been interested in this idea of the Gromov-Hausdorff Distance and have found some good articles online. However, I would like to know if there are any reputable reference books (hopefully which I can access online) which cover this topic. Couldn't find any online. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Did you try any of the books listed in the Wikipedia article about GH distance? Your library will likely to have at least some of these.

@MoisheKohan I didn't think of that! Thank you! I'll check those articles out.
